# SQL select to multiple count(*) outputs

Tags: sql

I have trouble to figure out how can I get out query that gives me data of how many people have received how many letters in certain campaign.
Like
Output:

```
Number of sent emails received             Number of client ID-s
       0                                 20145
       1                                  1244
       2                                  123
      etc..                                etc..
```

Current SQL I have written to get all the data from all the tables that I need to get the info.

```
SELECT 
account.EXT_STRING0 as client_ID,
account.EXT_STRING2 as Email,
activity.TEMPLATE_NAME as Template_name,
activity.NAME as campaign_name,
activity.EXECUTION_ID, -- unique campaign sent mail id
activity.SEND_DATE,
Activity.OPEN_DATE,
Activity.CLICK_DATE
FROM  
    crmautomation.oocke1_account account 
Join 
    crmautomation.oocke1_activity activity 
    ON 
     (account.object_id = activity.rep_contact)
left JOIN 
    crmautomation.OBJ_VAL val1
       ON val1.obj_row_id = activity.CAMPAIGN_TYPE AND (val1.OBJ_VAL_ID in(4250950)) 
left JOIN 
    crmautomation.OBJ_VAL val2
       ON val2.obj_row_id = activity.CAMPAIGN_TYPE AND (val2.OBJ_VAL_ID in(4250951))
where activity.TEMPLATE_NAME= ('cabin_surprise_ne')
and activity.SEND_DATE >('2015.12.01')
```

I thought some how I could use Group by to get the email count(*)-s, but I don't know how to do that.

EDIT:
Here is output of this sql

```
client_ID   Email              template_name      Execution_ID     Send_date
'343205'  random@gmail.com   Cabin_surprise_ne  0032-1fdsa-31    2015-12-14 23:08
```

And this mail has not been opened yet

Comment: please post the sample Input and output

Comment: In addition to `group by` you need to add `count(*)` to your select clause.  This is very basic sql.  Since you didn't know it, I've heard good things about the book, Teach Yourself SQL in 10 Minutes.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Sybase IQ Client 15.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to structure your query is as:

```
with cte as (
      <your query here>
     )
select cnt, count(*) as numClients, min(client_id), max(client_id)
from (select client_id, count(activity.rep_contact) as cnt
      from cte
      group by client_id
     ) x
group by cnt
order by cnt;
```

This is a "histogram-of-histogram" query, where you are trying to get counts.

EDIT:

On closer inspection, you will not get zero counts, because the `where` clause undoes the `left join`.  So, the query might look like:

```
SELECT cnt, count(*)
FROM (SELECT acc.EXT_STRING0 as client_ID, COUNT(a.rep_code) as cnt
      FROM crmautomation.oocke1_account acc left Join 
           crmautomation.oocke1_activity a 
           ON acc.object_id = a.rep_contact and
              a.TEMPLATE_NAME = 'cabin_surprise_ne'
              a.SEND_DATE > '2015.12.01' left JOIN 
           crmautomation.OBJ_VAL val1
           ON val1.obj_row_id = a.CAMPAIGN_TYPE AND (val1.OBJ_VAL_ID in (4250950)) left JOIN 
           crmautomation.OBJ_VAL val2
           ON val2.obj_row_id = a.CAMPAIGN_TYPE AND (val2.OBJ_VAL_ID in (4250951))
      GROUP BY acc.EXT_STRING0
     ) a
GROUP BY cnt
ORDER BY cnt;
```

I still don't fully understand the query.  You have two `left join`s to tables that are not used.  These can probably be removed, but you don't provide enough information about the data structure in your question.

Comment: Ok I will try to figure out and be back with more information after the weekend, but thank you for so far.

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*) count2, sum(a.count)
(
SELECT 
    count(*) as count,
    account.EXT_STRING0 AS client_ID,
    account.EXT_STRING2 AS Email,
    activity.TEMPLATE_NAME AS Template_name,
    activity.NAME AS campaign_name,
    activity.EXECUTION_ID,
    activity.SEND_DATE,
    Activity.OPEN_DATE,
    Activity.CLICK_DATE
FROM
    crmautomation.oocke1_account account
        JOIN
    crmautomation.oocke1_activity activity ON (account.object_id = activity.rep_contact)
        LEFT JOIN
    crmautomation.OBJ_VAL val1 ON val1.obj_row_id = activity.CAMPAIGN_TYPE
        AND (val1.OBJ_VAL_ID IN (4250950))
        LEFT JOIN
    crmautomation.OBJ_VAL val2 ON val2.obj_row_id = activity.CAMPAIGN_TYPE
        AND (val2.OBJ_VAL_ID IN (4250951))
WHERE
    activity.TEMPLATE_NAME = ('cabin_surprise_ne')
        AND activity.SEND_DATE > ('2015.12.01')
    group by account.EXT_STRING0 ) a -- client_ID 
    group by account.EXT_STRING2 -- Email
```

Comment: while this might answer the question, any code that is posted without at least a minimal amount of explanation with it, is likely not very useful for future readers of your answer.

Comment: I apologize for that, still new at this. Basically in the current query, add a count and groub by client ID, and create a outer query with another count but this time group by e-mail...in the outer query you only select the SUM of the previous count. hope this makes sense.

Comment: you can edit your answer by clicking on the `edit` button on the lower left of it and add that text, which I think already improves your answer (better than just leaving it as a comment)